# Vpython accessing object loaded from pdb protein file

Tags: python-3.x, object, vpython

using this .cif file:

https://files.rcsb.org/download/1MSC.cif and parsing in with https://pypi.org/project/pdbx-mmcif/

with this code (main.py) that uses Vpython 7.6.1 in python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Nov  11 17:40:03 2020

@author: Pietro

"""
import sys
from pdbx.reader.PdbxReader import PdbxReader

import time

from vpython import *


scene = canvas(title='Examples of Tetrahedrons',
     width=800, height=800,
     center=vector(0,0,0), background=color.black)

openz = open('./1msc.cif')

pRd = PdbxReader(openz)

data = []

pRd.read(data)

block = data[0]

atomsite = block.getObj("atom_site")

i=0
while True:
        atom =  atomsite.getValue("group_PDB",i)
        atomid = atomsite.getValue('label_atom_id',i)
        if atom =='ATOM':
            if atomid == 'CA':
                    aa = sphere(pos=vector(float(atomsite.getValue('Cartn_x',i)),float(atomsite.getValue('Cartn_y',i)),
                                           float(atomsite.getValue('Cartn_z',i))),radius=0.5)  
    
            i +=1
    
        else:
        
            break
      
print('fine')
```

I can show CA atoms in space as spheres. What I am missing is how to access the singles spheres ( objects as I understood) created by vpython, to be able to apply something like

```
sphere-object-number-1.color = color.red

sphere-object-number-1.color = color.blue
```

obviusly not in the same loop I created to display all the spheres ?
Please be kind I am not a Python expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard method is to make a list atoms = [] and when you create a sphere add it to the list, as atoms.append(sphere(.....)). Then you access the nth sphere with atoms[n], where n runs from 0 to atoms.length-1.

Comment: I'll comment that for VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users